# IBM-BPM custom logging

Tags: javascript, log4j, ibm-bpm

I am using IBM-BPM tool. I am trying to do the custom logging. I  have created a General System Service and attached the following script. It works very well in other process apps and in the previous snapshots in the same process app. But it does not work in the current environment. I am not able to figure out why is it not working. 
Please provide solution if any of you had faced such problems.

```
Packages.org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.configure(tw.env.logFilePath);
var logger = Packages.org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("FHG");
logger.error("sasf");
```

I have created the xml file and have placed in the location specified in logFilePath  variable.

Comment: Additional issues I've seen - are you running in a multi-node environment?  Does the file you want the logger to log to already exist?

Comment: I am working in single cluster environment if that is what you are asking. Yes.  I have the file.